# Debain i2c driver builtin no /dev/i2c-*

Tags: linux, debian, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

I've a problem and can't solve it by myself, soo...

I have an OrangePi zero and I use Debian on it.  The i2C module is a buildin driver but I don't know how to use it.

```
$ uname -a
Linux d621 5.3.5+ #2 SMP Fri Nov 15 16:24:33 CST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
$ find /sys/bus/platform -name *i2c*
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/mv64xxx_i2c
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/brcmstb-i2c
```

```
$ modprobe -D modprobe -D brcmstb-i2c
builtin i2c_brcmstb
```

```
$ modprobe i2c-brcmstb --first-time
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'i2c_brcmstb': Module already in kernel
```

Even though the module is already loaded in the kernel, I've no `/dev/i2c-*`. Someone can help me to get them.

EDIT: 
i2c-dev already builtin

```
$ modprobe i2c-dev -D
builtin i2c_dev
```

EDIT 2:

```
$ cat /boot/orangepiEnv.txt 
verbosity=1
logo=disabled
console=both
disp_mode=1920x1080p60
overlay_prefix=sun8i-h3
overlays=i2c0 i2c1 i2c2
```

[dmesg](https://controlc.com/5f7f469e)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly and why? The above module is a slave driver of PMIC. Are you sure it's related to i2c-dev?

Comment: I confused the PMIC module and the I2C driver, my goal is to get the /dev/i2c-X

Comment: I think you need to edit your /boot/orangepiEnv.txt (similar to /boot/armbianEnv.txt ??) to load overlays to enable the I2C controllers. For example: `overlays=i2c0 i2c1 i2c2`.

Comment: I've tried to add this line in the bootEnv file but that t doesn't change anything, I'm a little bit confused, it seem to be the right way (through what I read) but doesn't work. What I forget?

Comment: @ox223252 I don't really know what the differences are in the handling of orangepiEnv.txt on your system and armbianEnv.txt on an Armbian system, but I found [this forum thread](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=4495) where someone tried to do the same thing without much luck.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to load i2c-dev module as well, so just check that one if it's built in or loaded.
Also read through the demsg output, probably gives a hint if something goes wrong. If you can't find it, just share the dmesg output here, and we can look further

Comment: Ah, so this axp20x-i2c is an I2C device driver, not an i2c bus driver. Yo have the i2c bus driver loaded as well? A quick query shows that it should be i2c-bcm2708  on the OrangePi Zero.

Comment: I can't find bcm2708, but a brcmstb, `/sys/bus/platform/drivers/brcmstb-i2c` this one is loaded, is this one replace bcm2708 ?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be an i2c bus driver, hopefully the right one for your SOC. The other thing to check it is whether the i2c bus is enabled in your device tree. I don't know  which distribution you are using (Armbian perhaps?), but chances are that you can configure the device tree overlays in your boot config, to enable the i2c0 overlay. For Armbian for example you can set this in the "/boot/armbianEnv.txt" file, and for other distributions should be a similar env file on the boot partition.

Comment: I'm using `debian_stretch_server_linux5.3.5_v1.0`, and I found the file `/boot/orangepiEnv.txt`, But It's a too high level for my skill, I really don't know what should I do here. I tried to add some overlay, but nothing append.

Comment: Ok, could you please post the contect of that orangepiEnv.txt file and the output of the dmesg command? Then we will know more.

Comment: can't post dmesg system doesn't accept, soo you can found dmesg output here : [link](https://controlc.com/5f7f469e)